# Servlet response wrapper implementation leads to empty response

Tags: servlets, request, response, wrapper

I tried to implement servlet response wrapper to modify the response.
My goal is to add couple of  tags within html

This code works fine and  tags are properly added to html.
But the problem is that everything works  expected in non-IE7 browsers.
IE9/Firefox dont have any issues at all. Even IE7 from other's desktops dont have a problem. Only my IE7 browser have this issue, it simply displays empty page - complete white screen.
Even right-click view source displays html with empty head/body.

Through Fiddler I see response code is 200, but content length is 0.

If I do F5 twice simultaneously, Fidder shows this error

> Fiddler has detected a protocol violation in session #3.
>
> The Server did not return properly formatted HTTP Headers. HTTP headers
> should be terminated with CRLFCRLF. These were terminated with LFLF.

I am not manipulating any header attributes. Though it works everywhere else other than my browser, I want to know what is the problem as we cannot predict how browsers are out there just like mine.

Here is my code.

```
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest   = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    BrowserRequestWrapper requestWrapper    = new BrowserRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
    BrowserResponseWrapper responseWrapper  = new BrowserResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);
    PrintWriter responsePrintWriter         = response.getWriter();
    filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper,responseWrapper);
    try {           
        String responseString       = responseWrapper.toString();           
        String processedResponse    = getProcessedResponse(responseString);         
        response.setContentLength( processedResponse.length() );
        
        responsePrintWriter.write(processedResponse);
        //responsePrintWriter.flush();
        responsePrintWriter.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Logger.getLocation().errorT("doFilter","An exception has occured");
        Logger.getStackTrace(t);
    }
```

Here is wrapper class.

```
public class BrowserResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
private CharArrayWriter output;

public String toString() {
    return output.toString();
}
public BrowserResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response){
    super(response);
    output = new CharArrayWriter();
}

public PrintWriter getWriter(){     
    return new PrintWriter(output);
}
}
```